# SSRS data driven subscription to embed report in the email

Tags: reporting-services

I need to send some reports for a list of users, that list is changing everyday. so I need to set up a data driven subscription for the list of users, but I need to embed the report in each user's email body. I have set up the data driven subscription with rendering format set MHTML, but the email comes without any report.
Can someone help?

Comment: can you show your subscription settings as an image.. I use this all the time and it works just fine... unless the report is too big.. then it won't work as MHTML..

Comment: The report is small and it works with normal subscription. I can't add an image.

Comment: Just to clarify more, the email is part of the data driven, so each report needs to be embedded in different email.

Comment: If you deliver your data driven subscription as a PDF (anything other than MHTML) does it render correctly?

Comment: it generate blank pdf file. not sure why. but when run the report  from the reporting portal, it runs fine.

Comment: hey guys, i have resolved the issue. the data driven query was generating the wrong list, this caused the blank emails.